# how to Join only part of my first table to another table?

Tags: mysql

i have three tables:

1. `account` (which contain accounts Registered info and that Primary key is `ads_id`)
2. `ads_info` (which contain my advertising info and that Primary Key is `ads_id`)
3. `favorite_ads` (which that columns is `fav_id`, `acc_id` And `ads_id`) that specifies witch User Favorite which advertising.

Now i want to separate records which have `acc_id = 1` from `favorite_ads` table and then `outer-join` this records with all of my `ads_info` table records. 
can tell my any sql query do some thins like it for me?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT *
FROM ads_info AI
LEFT JOIN (SELECT fav_id, acc_id, ads_id
           FROM favorite_ads
           WHERE acc_id = 1) FA ON AI.ads_id = FA.ads_id
```